# Создать образ на флешку

Tags: образ, ubuntu

Возможно ли создать образ текущей Ubuntu(на флешку или диск), чтобы на другом компе загрузится с этой системы?  Заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос типовой.

Answer (score 1):

```
dd if=/dev/you_disk of=/dev/you_flash
```

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что я бы предложил сделать - использовать CloneZilla - он по сути для того и предназначен. Этот способ позволит перенести вашу систему на флешку.

Скрипт, который может преобразовать текущую установку в **liveCD iso**, называется remastersys.[Ubuntu Information](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html).Далее этот образ можно записать на Flash-накопитель стандартными средствами Ubuntu и использовать как live-систему.

Однако как я понял, его поддержка прекращена, и он устарел.НО есть его форк [ReLinux](https://relinuxkit.wordpress.com/).С ним я не знаком, но думаю, что там все даже проще чем раньше.

Сообщите какое решение вы решили использовать и что вышло.

Comment: Да, пользователи рапортуют об успешном применении CloneZilla для данной задачи.

Answer (score 0):

А если использование консоли пока для автора затруднительно, то Acronis Tru Image посвежее может создать такой образ и соответственно развернуть на другом компьютере.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно: [Remastersys - Ubuntu : Создание CD/DVD образа из установленной системы.](http://forum.runtu.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=but9cn74b2i37rcq1iemp366e2&topic=2741.0)

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu Information](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html).Очистить систему, отмонтировать ненужные разделы и вперёд.Если система ставилась с "чистого" дистрибутива, то всё будет отлично.

Answer (score 0):

clonezilla Вам в помощь. 
Можно созать iso а можно zip архив с установщиком на флешку.